# How to change Label AutoSize

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas, label

I added a Label to my program, which text can be entered by an inputbox.

But the text of the Label gets truncated because the size of the Label is too small.

I googled the problem and found the AutoSize method.

But in VB 2013 the Label has no such functionality.

Any ideas that might help?

Update: It's an WPF application

Comment: Hi. Sorry I didn't notice that I landed on the English site. Here is the translation: I added a Label to my program, which text can be entered by an inputbox. But the text of the Label gets truncated because the size of the Label is too small. I googled the problem and found the AutoSize Method. But in VB 2013 the Label has no such funcionality. Any ideas that might help?

Comment: `in VB 2013 the Label has no such funcionality` how did you come to that conclusion? is this WinForms?

Comment: I read that the command is >myLabel.AutoSize = true<. Trying this leads to an error. Maybe it's beacuse I have a WPF application and not windows forms

Answer (score 0):

If this is Winforms than there is an optioncalled

AutoEllipsis which will do just that

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that it's an WPF application. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This code will measure the length of the text, at a specified font, and set the label to that length.

`label.Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(label.Text, label.Font)`

Try that out and let me know if you need any further help.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that it's an WPF application. Any further ideas?